# Send Multilevel Form Data through API using JS

Tags: javascript, html, django, api, multipartform-data

I have five elements in my HTML form - 
1) A drop-down list to select TYPE.
2) Text input field for TITLE
3) Text input field for SUBSTANCE
4) TextArea field for TEXT
5) File input field for THUMBNAIL (single file)
6) File input field for FILES (multiple files)
I want to send a post request through API which should look like -

```
"type": "Some Type",
"title": "Some Title",
"substance": "Some Substance",
"text": "Some Text",
"thumbnail": binary_file_object,
"files": [
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_1},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_2},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_3},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_4},
       ]
```

Using JavaScript, I am able to achieve the following structure -

```
"files": [binary_file_object_1, binary_file_object_2, binary_file_object_3, binary_file_object_4]
```

but not the desired structure -

```
"files": [
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_1},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_2},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_3},
         {"file_name": binary_file_object_4},
       ]
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired structure ?
If possible, how ?
Feel free to ask for any missing information.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

---------    EDIT    ---------

Here are the HTML and JS code merged into one.
I am using static data for fields except "FILES" temporarily to keep focused on the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" multiple/>
  <button onclick="get_photo()">Submit</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const upld_files = [];

    const formData = new FormData();
    // Using static data for these fields temporarily
    formData.append("type", "FOOD");
    formData.append("title", "27th Food");
    formData.append("substance", "27th blog about food");
    formData.append("text", "This is the 27th blog about food");


    const handleImageUpload = event => {
      const u_files = event.target.files;

      for (i = 0; i < u_files.length; i++)
        {
          // temp_form = new FormData();
          // temp_form.append("file_name", u_files[i])
          // upld_files.push(u_files[i])
          // formData.append("files", temp_form);
          formData.append("files", u_files[i]);
        }
    }

    function get_photo()
    {
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.path)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
    }

    document.querySelector('#fileUpload').addEventListener('change', event => {
      handleImageUpload(event)
    })

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the js code?

Comment: What backend are you using? How in the formdata do you want it to be? The php way would be one part per `files` instance with `name=files[0][file_name]`, but I'm not sure all servers are able to handle that kind of format. Did you consider simply sending a JSON string in one part, and your binary files in the other and making the match back in your server-side by simply using the indices?

Comment: @Kaiido, I am using Django as backend. But I am trying not to manipulate the request at the backend but to get the request from the front end as the specified format. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I'm really not into django, but fast reading [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#s-binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form), it seems you should handle binary files separately from other fields anyway (like most backend), so creating that structure, would make very little sense.

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for your answer. It was really helpful.